# css not 'removing' on text color set to transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to after the DOM is loaded change a text inside a h1 to to change it's color to transparent, the blur effect works but not the color effect.

Here is the parts of my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#maintext h1').addClass('blur-text');
    });
</script>
```

```css
#main h1
    font-family: Neucha
    font-size: 14em
    color: $sbbqyellow
    margin-top: 35vh
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0)
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0)
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0)
    -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0)
    transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0)

.blur-text
    color: transparent
    text-shadow: 0 0 64px rgba(243, 203, 74, 1)
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="maintext" class="center">
        <h1>Sundsvall BBQ</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="center">
        <h3>Norrlands största grillevent</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `#main h1` css rule has a [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than your `.blur-text` rule, so the former overrides the latter.

Just make it so your .blur-text rule has a higher specifity

```
#maintext h1.blur-text {
   color:transparent;
}
```

Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#maintext h1').addClass('blur-text');
});
```

```css
#main h1 {
    font-family: Neucha;
    font-size: 14em;
    color: yellow;
    margin-top: 35vh;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
    -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
    transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
}

#maintext h1.blur-text {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 64px rgba(243, 203, 74, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="maintext" class="center">
    <h1>Sundsvall BBQ</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" class="center">
    <h3>Norrlands största grillevent</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Ofc. I should know that - to long time has passed since I worked with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selectors vary in specificity. '#main h1' where you're setting 'color:$sbbqyellow' will trump '.blur-text'. If you look in your dev tools inspector you'll probably see both styles applied, but in the wrong cascading order.

In order for your code to work exactly as intended change '.blur-text' to '#main h1.blur-text'. However I'd recommend trying to not IDs or elements, but rather single classes to better control the specificity, especially on things that toggle like this.

Comment: I know... was sometime ago I was fiddling with css so I have forgot stuff. Trying to solve another problem where I will use you approach. So thanks!